# Need select query for finding null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Student id = 4 has no value on course id = 20, how to display it with 
a select query?
The expected output is one row with the student details
Here is my SQL Code:

```
create table Students(
    student_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    lname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    fname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    age int NULL CHECK (age > 18),
    phone char(13) NULL CHECK (phone LIKE '[(][0-9][0-9][0-9][)][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

-- Creating the Course table:

```
create table Course(
    course_id int IDENTITY(10,10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title varchar(50) NULL,
    nb_hrs int NULL
);
```

-- Creating the Grades table:

```
create table Grades(
    course_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(course_id),
    student_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Students(student_id),
    grade float NOT NULL CHECK (grade BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
);
```

-- Inserting data into the tables:

```
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Salard', 'Jean', 19)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Le Bert', 'Antoine', 24)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Legendre', 'Pierre', 23)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Turcotte', 'Cedric', 24)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Tremblay', 'Alfredo', 22)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Dominguez', 'Silvia', 21)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Wright', 'Michelle', 30)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Sullivan', 'Anne', 20)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Petit-Clair', 'Cyril', 21)
INSERT INTO students(lname, fname, age) VALUES ('Herbert', 'Jean-Marc', 32)

INSERT INTO course(title, nb_hrs) VALUES ('P41', 45)
INSERT INTO course(title, nb_hrs) VALUES ('P42', 60)
INSERT INTO course(title, nb_hrs) VALUES ('P60', 60)
INSERT INTO course(title, nb_hrs) VALUES ('P61', 60)

INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 1, 78)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 1, 85)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 2, 80)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 2, 90)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 1, 84)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 10, 96)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 2, 61)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 9, 89)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 10, 73)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 3, 45)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 5, 80)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 6, 33)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 4, 67)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 3, 84)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 5, 35)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 5, 85)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 7, 80)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 3, 67)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 6, 77)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 7, 80)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 4, 33)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 6, 56)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 7, 87)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 9, 89)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 10, 73)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 1, 89)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 9, 18)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 2, 50)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 5, 79)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (30, 8, 37)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 3, 67)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 4, 77)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 8, 75)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 7, 56)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (40, 8, 87)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 8, 38)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (20, 6, 92)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 9, 79)
INSERT INTO grades(course_id, student_id, grade) VALUES (10, 10, 97)
```

(This is a little bit of extra text, just so I am able to edit the code fences in ... )

Comment: There is no select query

Comment: i need the select query sorry

Comment: can you pls highlight the important inserts. I have no db here to run the statements

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: We don't write code for you -- you have to make an attempt and we'll help you.  I think you'll need to research either a left join and a where null clause OR perhaps a where not exists clause.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service website.  You should at least do something.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer:

select s.student_id,s.lname,s.fname,s.age,s.phone 
from Students s
where s.student_id in (select student_id from grades g group by student_id having count(student_id) < 4 )

THANKS TO EVERYONE THOUGH

Answer (score -1):

```
select t1.* from students t1 left outer join grade t2 on t1.student_id=t2.student_id and t2.course_id=20
where t1.student_id=4
```

Comment: It works ! I putted the condition on course_id in the jointure and not in where